# why is the recursion used in finding the factorial of a number?

Tags: c, codeblocks

Why can't we use it directly in `main`?
Why should there be a recursion?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int factorial(int n);
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter an positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Factorial of %d = %ld", n, factorial(n));
    return 0;
}

int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n!=1)
    return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use recursion. It's one of way of calculating factorial. You can do the same using a loop too.

Comment: You are right, there shouldn't be any recursion when computing factorials. Unfortunately, it's one of the easiest examples on which the recursion can be demonstrated, so instructors often go for it without a disclaimer that one shouldn't use recursion in situations of this kind.

Comment: What should do the program when n ==1?

Comment: It should return `1` because `n! = 1`; this is also true for `n == 0`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use recursion. Because C doesn't support so-called *optimization of tail recursion calls*, you should avoid recursion where it could be replaced by a simple loop. But C does support recursion *at all*, and such factorial is the simpliest example of recursive function, if we don't pay attention to the fact that it is not an optimal code.

Simpliest usecase of recursion where it is actually *needed* could be a directory tree go-round. If you try to replace recursion with a loop in the latter case, you will get much less readable code and you're still gonna need a stack with O(N) memory where N is maximum directory nesting level, so, in most common cases, you wouldn't achieve anything useful from this optimisation attempt.

Also, pay attention to the fact that vanilla C lacks built-in support of dynamic data structures. You can, of course, implement a variable sized stack by using heap memory accessible via `malloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()` C runtime library's functions, but this approach will increase *complexity* of your project. You will have to look after your pointers to avoid leaks and memory corruption.

Comment: Interesting historical note: support for recursion was one of C's big selling points and a notable feature at the time it was being developed (well, really it was still B at that point), specifically because people wanted to write functions in a "more mathematical" style. Fortran, C's historical competitor, wouldn't support it for years. Same goes for the ternary operator.

Comment: @Leushenko I've never used Fortran, but from what a know about this language it always had ovewhelming advantage in support on multidimesional arrays extensively used in scientific computing and it doesn't suffer from pointer aliasing problem, so it is much easier to perform aggressive optimizations in the compiler. And there's all those IBM patents on top of it.

Comment: True. A related historical quirk is that B and C were never intended to be the high-performance beasts C and C++ have become today - they were for writing "high"-level code that needed clarity and portability more than optimization (B even started life as an interpreted language).